# Why is OpenJPA calling UPDATE before DELETE?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, openjpa

I'm trying to delete a parent entity that has a one-to-many parent-child relationship using `entityManager.remove(parent)`. However, from the SQL log I see OpenJPA calling `UPDATE` first and trying to set null for a `NOT NULL` field.

```
executing prepstmnt 773394836 UPDATE child SET parent_id = ? WHERE parent_id = ? [params=(null) null, (long) 16]
executing prepstmnt 1127292223 DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = ? [params=(long) 16]
executing prepstmnt 1297966852 DELETE FROM child WHERE lookup_id = ? AND parent_id = ? [params=(int) 1, (long) 16]
```

How do I configure my classes to prevent this first `UPDATE` call?

My classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Child> children;

    // getters, etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@IdClass(ChildPrimaryKey.class)
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long parentId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "lookup_id")
    private int lookupId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
        nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    // getters, etc.
}
```

My DB tables (in MySQL):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
  `lookup_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `parent_id` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`, `lookup_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_library_code_idx` (`parent_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_library_code`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id` )
    REFERENCES `parent` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *exactly* sure what is causing JPA to decide to execute those queries, however, I do notice a couple of issues with your mappings.

First, you're not specifying the `mappedBy` element on your `@OneToMany` annotation (i.e. you're not telling OpenJPA that `Child` is the owner of the relationship). This would be my first guess as to why you're seeing this behavior. From the [API specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html):

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the mappedBy element must be
>   used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that
>   is the owner of the relationship.

To fix this, change your `Parent`'s `@OneToMany` to include the `mappedBy` element and drop the `@JoinColumn`:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
             fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Child> children;
```

Additionally, I've noticed you are trying to use `Parent`'s ID as part of `Child`'s ID and have two fields on `Child` mapping to the same PK column (`parent` and `parentId`). The preferred way to handle this is with [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html):

```
  @Id
  private long parentId;

  // ...

  @MapsId("parentId")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Using mappedBy instead of @JoinColumn causes an exception on insertion because OpenJPA tries to put 0 as parent_id: `Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (``test``.``child``, CONSTRAINT ``fk_library_code`` FOREIGN KEY (``parent_id``) REFERENCES ``parent`` (``id``) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) {prepstmnt 972578961 INSERT INTO child (lookup_id, parent_id) VALUES (?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (long) 0]} [code=1452, state=23000]`. I think mappedBy is intended for join tables.

Comment: After investigating some more, using `mappedBy` is the right way to go in this case. However, child and parent entities must be managed separately. For example, `parent_id` has to be set to the correct value on the child, child entities must be removed manually, etc. `@MapsId` is not needed in this case.

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky If you use `@MapsId`, `parentId` will be automatically copied from `Parent` for you.  Your use-case is exactly what is described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html): "_Designates a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship attribute that provides the mapping for ... a simple primary key of the parent entity_". Also, you shouldn't have to remove the children separately...can you show your updated entities?

Comment: If I use `@MapsId`, I get a nonsense exception: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1.lookupId' in 'field list'`. I don't think `@MapsId` is intended to be used with `@IdClass`

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky You might be right...I didn't notice you had the `@IdClass` specified. Have you tried using an [`EmbeddedId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html)? Also, I didn't think my answer solved your problem...how did you end up resolving your issue?

Comment: using `mappedBy` solves the delete issue. The initial `UPDATE` is not longer called. Yes, `@EmbeddedId` with `@MapsId` works here. However, when using `@MapsId` I need to set children to null before deleting parent or else I get an `OptimisticLockException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hypothesis.

What I think is happening is that UPDATE statement is there to avoid a constraint violation when the DELETEs are executed.  Or at least, that's why OpenJPA *thinks* it needs to do that UPDATE.

There are two possibilities:

- OpenJPA is right and the UPDATE is necessary
- OpenJPA is wrong and the UPDATE is redundant

I'd suggest that you set up your database with a related "parent" and "child" rows, and then attempt to *manually* DELETE one or the other row *without* doing the UPDATE.  That will determine if the UPDATE is *really* necessary.

Depending on the outcome, either ignore the problem, try altering the schema and/or the annotations, or look to see if there is bug report / work-around in the OpenJPA issue tracker.  (You could also try some experiments to see whether Hibernate behaves the same way and/or whether this is specific to MySQL.)

Comment: I suspect the update is failing (it's trying to set a PK/NOT NULL column to NULL)

Comment: I tried the manual DELETE in the database. Only the `DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = ?` is needed to do the delete. UPDATE is not necessary. The second DELETE of the child is also not necessary.